# TFS On Prem to VSOnline migration template customization possible false positive with OPSHub

Tags: tfs, opshub, azure-devops

wondering if anyone else has experienced anything similar and has overcome it.  I am using OpsHub to migrate from an on premise 2012 TFS to VSOnline.  I've set up my project with perms according to the instructions provided by Opshub.  I ran a dry run of the migration to a personal instance of VSOnline in early December.  Now I am trying to follow the same migration steps to our company's vsonline instance.  I've set up everything the same.  I am receiving an error that sure seems like a false positive.  The utility is reporting that the WIT for Code Review Response has been customized.  Specifically the field Reviewed By has been customized.  I've opened up both WIT's and compared them.  The only thing that is different is that on the 2012 WIT it didn't contain the rules ALLOWEXISTINGUSER and VALIDUSER and the Reportable field was blank.  I tried adding them to the 2012 WIT but that didn't alleviate that problem and I set to the Reportable field to Dimension to match the 2015 WIT.  I've checked the spelling on the 2012 WIT, it is the same.  This has not alleviated the issue.  Has anyone experienced and better yet, solved this?  If so, would you mind sharing?

Comment: What version of OVSMU are you using? There was a change recently done to VSTS leading to this mismatch. The latest version of the tool has this issue handled. Please try with our newest release.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest version, OVSMU-V2.0.0.004 and still receive the same error.  Just frustrating that this worked perfectly when I tried this before the holidays and now scheduled downtime for the org to do it for real and this is completely blocking us.  What are our options?

Comment: Hi, we have verified this at our end. The process templates have NOT changed again. Most likely it's a cache issue. Can you clear out the contents of %localappdata%/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/X.0/Cache/ (Where X can be 3, 4, 5 and/or 6)

Comment: You will have to close the tool and any instances of Visual Studio that are open before clearing the cache.

Comment: Clearing of the cache for version 4.0, 5.0 and 6.0 didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restore the WIT definition to the original 2012 template rather than update it to match 2015 template. To do this, [download](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181510(v=vs.120).aspx) the original process template used to create your team project and import the WIT XML definition files for Code Review Response using [witadmin importwitd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd312129.aspx).

Refer to this link for details: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/migrate-team-projects-vs

Comment: I uploaded the an original TFS 2012 Agile template to the project instance.and still receive the same error.

Comment: @JohnSheppard Then this may caused by this issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2266743. This issue should be fixed in the next deployment, try the migration again after this issue is fixed.

Comment: Do you know when the next deployment is going to be?